# Allow approved and logged in users to download files from Google Cloud Storage bucket

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-storage

I have a bucket on Google Cloud Storage. It contains multiple `.csv` files. I would like to create a WordPress site that allows me to give access to logged in users to download files from this bucket.

Is the easiest way to do this to simply create a basic page behind a log-in screen with a list of download URLs from GCS?

This seems like:

1. It would be unsecure on the GCS side (i.e., I have to allow anyone that has the link to download it, so it could be shared by a logged in user with someone that is not a user on my website)
2. The website and the GCS bucket are not synced (i.e., if I upload a file to my GCS bucket, I have to go to the WordPress website and add a link to the download URL).

I would like to have it set-up so that

1. In order to download a file you have to be logged in to my website and you have be approved by GCS to download a file.
2. I only have to worry about uploading media to my GCS bucket and not updating individual download links on my website as I will have hundreds of files.

If it is possible to assign specific users permission to download only specific sub-folders or individual files in GCS, that would be a bonus.

I have looked at the wp-stateless plugin but this doesn't seem to really accomplish what I want. This just takes the normal WordPress media functionality and stores them in a new bucket on GCS but I already have hundreds of files in a GCS bucket that I would like to serve.

Comment: Have you tried to use Signed URL? This is a URL that provides limited permission and time to make a request. In your application you would create a Signed URL for the file and do a HTTP redirect to the said file. You can refer with these two links: [1](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signing-urls-manually) and [2](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls)

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, anyone with the signed URL can still download the file within the specified expiry time. If there is not a more elegant solution, I will probably just end up doing this with 30 second expiry times or something.

Comment: 1) I do something similar. My backend code lists the objects in Cloud Storage and generates special URLs to my backend. When the backend receives a request, it generates a signed URL and redirects the client to Cloud Storage using the signed url. That way I can create signed URLs as required with short durations. I also cache the Cloud Storage object list for X period of time to reduce API calls to Cloud Storage. 2) How well do you understand WordPress plugin development? The task is fairly easy if you know the WordPress API and the Cloud Storage PHP SDK.

Comment: @JohnHanley not very well unforunately - I do primarily medical research and strictly stasitical programming. But I get a lot of asks for various datasets repeatedly and I want to design as simple a website as possible where users can make an account, I can authorize them for whatever datasets they are authorized to have, and they can download them at their leisure. Better than the get email, find dataset, send dataset process I have going on. Any resources or code repositories you can point to would be helpful.

Comment: Note: the process of generating signatures is CPU intensive. Do not blindly create pages of signed URLs unless you have an instance size that can support that CPU load.

Comment: Also, I realize I can just make a DropBox or Google Drive and authorize users to download files that way, but my intent was for this to eventually comprise a small part of a much larger internal site for my program.

Comment: The code that I wrote is a commercial application. I am not aware of a repository or example code. Most companies that provide this level of WordPress plugin charge for them. You mention **at their leisure** but also mention URLs valid for 30 seconds.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250455/discussion-between-dylan-russell-and-john-hanley).

Comment: If your understanding of the WordPress API and the Cloud Storage API is limited, you have a several month long project to build something similar to what I mentioned when you factor in security, performance, and user experience. The WordPress learning curve is long. If the user base is small, you might consider using Google Cloud IAM and granting the users rights to Google Cloud Storage and bypass custom development.